# Query to compare branches of a journey after a percentage split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, data, custom-activity

I ran a journey where I used a decision split to separate the audience into 4 branches and then sent each branch the same series of emails with varying wait times in between sends. Now I want to measure which branch performed better in terms of opens/clicks/goal achievement.

I can locate the Triggered Send Name and Triggered Send External Key for each email activity by viewing the activity summary in Journey Builder, but I can't find any of those values in any of the fields when I query the _JourneyActivity data view. I also can't figure out which version ID goes to which version number.

In short, I can't figure out how to query data views for activities I can see in Journey Builder. What's the most efficient way to query data on a specific email activity in a specific version of a journey?

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right what you are missing might be the following information:

> JourneyActivityObjectID corresponds to TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID in the _Sent, _Open, _Click, and _Bounce, data views.

With that information you can query data regarding opens, clicks and so on. I hope this helps :)

Comment: That is a good place to start, but how can I be sure which JourneyActivityObjectID goes to which Email Activity in Journey Builder? I need to be able to query for specific values.

Comment: For that you can use the ActivityExternalKey. That is your identifier for each activity.

Comment: I see! But the ActivityExternalKeys that are returned look like "EMAILV2-10". How should I interpret that?

Comment: I thought that the External Key was editable. But I cant find that option in the UI. Maybe there is an option via API. Even then it would be quite annoying to go through all activities. Sorry :/